# Django template nested for loop

Tags: python, django-templates

I have 2 tables:

```
Table1: [A-Foriegn Key, field1]
Table2: [Table1-Foriegn Key, field2]
```

I want to display a list with distinct values of Table1 field1 if items are present in Table2. and inside that list I want to display all the elements of Table2 corresponding to that field1 of Table1.

I am trying :

```
{% for t1 in Table1 %}
   Display field1 of t1
   {% for t2 in Table2 %}
      Display field2 of t2.
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Table 1:

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║ Id ║  EventName   ║ FK   ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ Christmas    ║  56  ║
║  2 ║ Black Friday ║  18  ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

Table 2:

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║ ID ║  Image       ║ FK   ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ image1_url   ║  1   ║
║  2 ║ image2_url   ║  1   ║
║  3 ║ image3_url   ║  2   ║
║  4 ║ image4_url   ║  2   ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

I want to display : Christmas and BlackFriday in a list.

And on clicking element from the list, I want to display all url for that particular event. 
Like on clicking Christmas: image1_url and image2_url should be displayed.

I dont want to make AJAX requests.

Comment: Can you give sample data in table and sample output?

Comment: I have added sample data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use foreign key mappings in the templates to reference objects.

Suppose you have two tables Table1 and Table2, with a mapping like Table1 -> Table2, with a foreign key field in Table2 referencing Table1, you can do something like this:

Your `views.py` would be something like this:

```
table1 = Table1.objects.all() 
table2 = Table2.objects.all() 
return render('template_name.html',{'table1':table1, 'table2':table2})
```

then your html template will be like:

```
{% for table1Instace in table1 %}
    
    {% for table2Instance in table1Instace.table2_set.all %}
    
    <!--Print table elements here-->
    
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

where your `table2Instance` will be an objects of the row(s) in table2 corresponding to their foreign key mapping in table1.

Comment: Two minor corrections to the above answer. May be the query for Table 2 is not required. Also in templates we cannot use () after 'all()'. This is similar to using '.items()' in view and simply 'items' in templates.

Comment: table1Instace.table2_set.all   can i get first element from this list

Answer (score 1):

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)

class Items(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    rate = models.FloatField(default=0)
    category_id = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

views.py

```
def test_category(request):
    s = Category.objects.all()
    return_dict = {
        's' :   s        
    }
    return render(request, 'base.html', return_dict)
```

```
{% for item in s%}
    {{ item.name }}
    {% for x in item.items_set.all %}
        -- {{ x.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: s must be queryset of Items.